# ASP.NET 4.0 YouTube Video

Tags: asp.net, video, youtube

Am tasked with building an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms site to support playback of YouTube videos. Will build it as a HTML5 site but am trying to weave my way through the maze of video formats/codecs.

I do not want to use plugins and I want it to have cross-browser support:

- IE9/IE8/IE7
- Firefox
- Chrome
- Safari

Majority of traffic will be IE. For the other browsers, latest versions will suffice.

I'm looking to embed the videos directly. Really just need to know how to cater for the different browsers without use of plugins (incl. Google Frame).

Can anyone provide some guidance/direction?

**UPDATE**

Per Stilgar's answer, there probably will be no advantage gained to creating this as HTML5

Comment: You want to be able to embed youtube videos or you want to build your own video serving system?

Comment: Just embedding them (I updated the Q) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to embed videos from youtube you don't need to care about codecs and browser support. You only need to render the Youtube embed code on your page which is just an iframe. The user can get the html by clicking share > embed on youtube or you can generate it programatically when the user pastes an URL to an youtube video. The code looks like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Kt82xgsm9N8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you do this youtube will provide a player for the user. The player will be based on the user's settings IN YOUTUBE. For example if the user has selected HTML5 videos on youtube he will get an HTML5 player for his browser. If the user has opted in for Flash or is using an older browser youtube will serve the Flash player. Also some videos (those with ads) are only available with Flash.

Basically even if you want to do something else you can't. That's how Youtube works and you want to embed their videos not serve your own. However I don't see why you will want something different from what they provide. They make their best to support every browser in the best way.

And just FYI the video tag is supported on the latest version of all browsers and is not supported in IE8 and IE7. There are two codecs (with 2 formats) that are important right now these are H.264(mp4) and VP8 (webm)
Safari (including Safari on iOS) and IE9+ (including IE on Windows Phone) support H.264
Chrome, Firefox and Opera support VP8
If you want to support all browsers via the video tag you need to provide both encodings and encode the video twice.
If you want to support IE7 and IE8 your only option is a plugin (be it Flash, Silverlight or just regular old Media Player Plugin that comes by default)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself yet but I've heard some good things about jPlayer. Check out http://jplayer.org/.

One thing to keep in mind is that while many browsers support HTML5 semantics, they don't support the same codecs. You'll need to encode your video into the various formats that each browser supports. Wikipedia has an example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video.

```
<video poster="movie.jpg" controls>
    <source src='movie.webm' type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'/>
    <source src='movie.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
    <source src='movie.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <p>This is fallback content</p>
</video>
```

Comment: This will not work in IE8 and IE7 (and according to the question support is required). You need Flash fallback. Also if support for older versions of Firefox (older than 4) is not required you may skip ogv as Firefox supports WebM

Comment: @IrishChieftain you cannot support video on IE8 and IE7 without plugin whatever you do.

Comment: @Stilgar what's the main hurdle?

Comment: The main hurdle is that HTML did not include support for video before the video tag and IE9 is the first version of IE that supports the video tag. Samo goes for versions of other browsers that are old enough. BTW you did not answer my comment on question. It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Marc, can you explain the codecs for the MP4, not familiar with them?

Comment: The codec for mp4 is H.264 As it happens it is the same codec used for Flash and Silverlight videos